# MATLAB line continuation within string

Tags: string, matlab

In MATLAB, `...` is used to continue a line to the next line. But if I want to continue a long string within quotation, what can I do? `...` will be treated as a part of the string itself.
Using `[]` is not a perfect solution since in most cases I use `sprintf/fprintf` to parse a long string like sql query. Using `[]` would be cumbersome. thanks.

Comment: Note - this is related to character arrays, not strings, per se, which is a separate type in newer versions of Matlab `a = 'a character array'`, `b = "a string"`

Answer (score 16):

If you put the string in brackets, you can build it in several pieces:

```
s = ['abc' 'def' ... 
     'ghi'];
```

You can then split that statement into several lines between the strings.

Comment: If the strings are hard coded, this is definitely a good approach. I took the liberty of editing so that the usage of `...` becomes clearer =)

Comment: But he explicitly said he didnt want [] ?

Comment: this is to break the string rather than continue a long string. I really want to use sprintf with paremeter parsing rather than brackets.

Comment: What is the problem with `s = sprintf(['abc' 'def' '%d'], 1);` ?

Comment: @ groovingandi, the problem is that it is more cubersome than simply write a very long line. I was hoping a better a better solution but it seems it is a limitation of Matlab.

Answer (score 9):

```
answer=['You can divide strings '...
    ,'by adding a comma '... 
    ,'(as you probably know one year later).'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use strcat or horzcat, which gives you somewhat more options than [], including the ability to mix in variables along with the hardcoded values.