# Enforce maximum line length limit on Matlab editor

Tags: matlab, formatting, editor

How could I enforce the max line length limit in Matlab editor such that it would be split when it over the max limit?

For example , the follow too long line   -

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
```

would be changed automatically to  -

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 ...
7 8 9 10]
```

**Edit:**

You can read about the `...` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226491/matlab-line-continuation-within-string)  .

Comment: Re: Hacking the Editor, I don't know if what you want is possible, but you'll want to be comfortable with a bit of Java and look here: [http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/accessing-the-matlab-editor/](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/accessing-the-matlab-editor/).

Comment: You know there's many good reasons *AGAINST* enforcing max. line length right? It's all right for comments, but certainly NOT for code...

Comment: You could also post-process the m-file with a simple script to break long lines...

Comment: Why not just do it by hand? You are a better judge of when to enforce the limit, where to actually break the lines, and when to just let it slide (for example if a line only goes over by 1 or two characters). Additionally, some long lines are better to be broken down into multiple expressions.

Comment: Why don't you just edit code in a text editor and then run MATLAB from the command line? Ideally you'd avoid MATLAB altogether but if you must use it *and* you want to enforce this convention then you should use a text editor capable of this kind of extension. I can almost guarantee that you'll have to hack around on the Java side of MATLAB if you want to change some aspect of the interface. On the other hand vim and emacs are relatively easy to extend compared to that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your lines more readable in the command window (but not the editor) so you don't have to keep scrolling to the right, you can enable command window line wrapping in the Matlab Preferences (Preferences -> Command Window -> Wrap Lines). There's no such option for the editor.